# Provider org.ehcache.jcache.JCacheCachingProvider not a subtype in Tomcat /lib

Tags: tomcat, guice, ehcache

When using ehcache as a regular dependency and having it loaded with the WAR/lib folder things are good.  But as described on the ehcache site, when attempting to re-deploy we are getting memory leak issues:

https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/integrations/tomcat.html#class-loader-memory-leak

I'm attempting to clean these up, but after doing the following:

- Add `<scope>provided</scope>` to project for org.ehcache.jcache
- Place javax.cache, org.ehcache.jcache and org.slf4j jar files in Tomcat/lib

I'm getting the error:

Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.cache.spi.CachingProvider: Provider org.ehcache.jcache.JCacheCachingProvider not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:231)

which is odd, since https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache-jcache/blob/v1.0.1/ehcache-jcache/src/main/java/org/ehcache/jcache/JCacheCachingProvider.java is implementing `javax.cache.spi.CachingProvider`

Removing `<scope>provided</scope>` and allowing the war to override the Tomcat/lib results in everything going back to normal (memleak and all).

I've gone down the maven dependency tree for `org.ehcache.jcache` and it looks like there are only the 4 jars required.  This could be an issue with versioning? maybe replacing `org.ehcache.jcache`/`net.sf.ehcache` with `org.ehcache.ehcache` might resolve the issue?  But i'd like to just check on here before going through that process.